# Laravel localization in 404 page

Tags: php, laravel, localization

Hello I have an issue with laravel localization

I've made language switcher and currently selected language doesn't work on 404 pages (it works if I return abort(404) in controller manualy), it always shows content on default locale defined in config/app.php

My middleware code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetLanguageCookie
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->hasCookie('language')) {
            $cookie = $request->cookie('language');
            app()->setLocale($cookie);

            return $next($request);
        } else {
            $response = $next($request);
            $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('language', 'en'));
            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how can I make this working? So all automaticaly shown 404 pages show content in currently selected language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it with help of @ArthurSamarcos

app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($request->hasCookie('language')) {
        // Get cookie
        $cookie = $request->cookie('language');
        // Check if cookie is already decrypted if not decrypt
        $cookie = strlen($cookie) > 2 ? decrypt($cookie) : $cookie;
        // Set locale
        app()->setLocale($cookie);
    }

    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Note that you should check cookie length (by example mine is 2 chars when decrypted), before trying to decrypt it, because sometimes it returns already decrypted cookie.

Answer (score 2):

If you have default error handling, look for this file:

app\Exceptions\Handler.php

Change the render method to something like this:

```
    /**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        if(\Request::hasCookie('language')) {
            $cookie = \Request::cookie('language');
            app()->setLocale($cookie);
           //.... etc
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Ive tried this already, and it's not working for me, i dont know why
EDIT: Managed to fix it by using decrypt() to cookie